# fat free framework basket class find all items in basket not working

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Hello as it's written in F3 documentation here : http://fatfreeframework.com/basket#load
you can get all the results of the basket like this

`$result = $basket->find();  // array of basket items, if any`

But when I tried it I get the following error :

`Internal Server Error

`Missing argument 1 for Basket::find(), called in /var/www/***/controller.php on line 55 and defined`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed some days ago: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/commit/c16332c7cc2d24ed2e98e3654e182211e6e09db5

Fetch the nightly build and try again ;)

Comment: can I find an item by the _id that the cart assigns to each of it's items ? I tried issuing basket->find('_id','something')or basket-get('_id','something') but no luck at all  @ikkez

Comment: As far as I know there is no such auto increment id in Basket. It's just a key value store, with the ability of adding multiple kv-pairs to one item... Like a whole multidimensional array... the find method is just the pick the right 1st level array key in there

Answer (score 0):

@ikkez I added this function inside lib/basket.php in order to return the item of the cart by id

```
function findById($cartID){
    $out=array();
    foreach($_SESSION[$this->key] as $id=>$item){
        if($id==$cartID){
          return $item;
        }

    }
}
```

Hope it will help somebody..